# How should a IsPrimaryPhone field be modeled in the database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

A contact can have one or more phone numbers.  A way is needed to set one of them as the "Primary" phone number.

What is the best way to model that?

The way I usually see it done is to simply add a field called "is_primary" to the phone.  Yet for this to work, when that field is set to true for one record, then all other related phone numbers needs to be set to false.

Is there a way to model it through a relation so only one bit of data needs to be updated?

It seems this could be done through a linking table called PrimaryPhone with 
ContactId and PhoneId.  If the link exists for a ContactId/PhoneId, then it would be used in the UI to show that it was the primary.  If the primary changed, it would only be a matter of changing the one record.

Or is some other way this should be done?

Comment: Sure. Assuming you have two tables (Contacts and PhoneNumbers) it is pretty simple. You have a column in Contacts for PrimaryPhoneNumberID and it contains the ID of the PhoneNumber.

Comment: The linking table you are describing is typically what would be used for a many to many relationship. Don't really need that here I don't think.

Comment: Excellent idea. Should have thought of that.  If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two tables (Contacts and PhoneNumbers) it is pretty simple. You have a column in Contacts for PrimaryPhoneNumberID and it contains the ID of the PhoneNumber. This ensures you can never have more than 1 marked as the primary at any one point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I might try mine like:

```
    CREATE TABLE Contact
        (ContactID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,CreateDate datetime
        )
    GO

    CREATE TABLE Phone
        (PhoneID int identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
        ,ContactID int  not null 
        ,[Key] varchar(20) not null
        ,[Value] varchar(20) not null
        ,[Status] varchar(20) not null
        )
    GO
    ALTER TABLE Phone 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_cnst FOREIGN KEY (ContactID)     
        REFERENCES Contact (ContactID)     
    GO
    ALTER TABLE phone ADD CONSTRAINT UX_Constraint UNIQUE (ContactID, [Status])
    GO

    INSERT contact SELECT 1, GETDATE()

    INSERT INTO phone (ContactID, [Key], Value, Status) VALUES (1, 'Office', '455-1212', 'Alternate')
    INSERT INTO phone (ContactID, [Key], Value, Status) VALUES (1, 'Home', '555-1212', 'Alternate2')
    INSERT INTO phone (ContactID, [Key], Value, Status) VALUES (1, 'Cell', '555-1000', 'Primary')
    INSERT INTO phone (ContactID, [Key], Value, Status) VALUES (1, 'Cell', '555-1001', 'MistressHotline')

    GO

    SELECT *
    FROM Phone

    GO


    DROP TABLE  phone, Contact
```

And then of course go query it to see if it will work out or not.

Thanks